# Primefaces Command Button Ajax Works Only Once

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have the following command button which enters only once in the saveData method:

```
<p:commandButton id="saveBtn" 
    value="#{messages['um3.common.label.save']}"            
    actionListener="#{advisorBean.saveData}"            
    disabled="#{advisorBean.disabledSave}">             
    <f:param name="positionId" value="#{advisorBean.positionId}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Here is the saveDate method signature: public void saveData().

Also, the page containing the button is inserted into a layout and the button sits in a primefaces panel.

Layout Page:

```
<h:body>
    <p:layout fullPage="true">
       <p:layoutUnit>
            <ui:insert name="footer">
```

Button Page:

```
<ui:define name="footer">
            <p:panel id="footer">
                <p:commandButton id="saveBtn" ...
```

Could you please advise?

Andrei

Comment: Please post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not these kinds of code snippets. And post [more info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) The latter also contains some more details about a jsf mcve

Comment: set `ajax="false"` for `p:commandButton` and test it, Does any exception is thrown?

Comment: With ajax false it works every time, I haven't seen any errors, also the managed bean is view scoped.

Comment: Servlet version used: 2.5

Comment: are there any errors on browser javascript console?

Comment: There was an access permission error, I've fixed it, but the problem still persists.

Answer (score -1):

I found that the server was stopping and restarting by itself, after a clean everything worked fine.

Comment: I doubt this was the cause of the problem